# Extracting route parameters from MVC 5 route templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

My project is using the following code to generate MVC routed URLs for the given `routeName` and `routeValues`:

```
public class RouteBuilder
{
    public string GetUrl(string routeName, object routeValues)
    {
        return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
            new RequestContext(new MockHttpContextBase(string.Empty), new RouteData()),
            routeName,
            new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues)
        )?.VirtualPath;
    }
}
```

For example, given the following route definition:

```
public MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("Foo", "{bar}/{quux}")]
    public IActionResult MyControllerMethod(MyModel model) {  }
}
```

we call:

```
// yields "zod/baz"
var routedUrl = RouteBuilder.GetUrl("Foo", new
{
    bar = "zod",
    quux = "baz",
});
```

The problem comes in with the route values object passed to `GetUrl`. Out of necessity it can be any type of object, including an anonymous one as demonstrated in the example. But this is problematic because if there are any typos in the object's definition, the route template won't match and the URL won't be built:

```
// yields null!
var routedUrl = RouteBuilder.GetUrl("Foo", new
{
    baz = "zod", // oops, typo in 1st param name!
    quux = "baz",
});
```

This is even more of an issue because it can only be caught at runtime.

A potential solution is this:

```
public class MyControllerMethodRouteParameters
{
    string bar { get; set; }
    string quux { get; set; }
}

public MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("Foo", "{" + nameof(MyControllerMethodRouteParameters.bar) + "}/{" + nameof(MyControllerMethodRouteParameters.quux ) + "}")]
    public IActionResult MyControllerMethod(MyModel model) {  }
}

public class RouteBuilder
{
    private string GetUrl(string routeName, object routeValues) { /* as before */ }

    public string GetUrl(MyControllerMethodRouteParameters params)
    {
        return GetUrl(GetRouteNameFor(params.GetType(), params));
    }
}
```

But it has a large drawback in terms of developer effort: when adding a new controller method, you also have to remember to add a route parameters class, a `GetUrl` overload for it, and a routename => route parameters type mapping. Easy to forget to do, and it also feels like unnecessary repetition since all of the necessary parameters and their types are already defined in the `RouteAttribute`.

So my idea was to generate the needed code via a T4 template, by reflecting over the assembly, grabbing all `RouteAttribute`s and pulling the route name and template out of them, then parsing the template for the property names of the route parameters class. It's this last hurdle that I've fallen at, because while I know I can probably write a regex(es) to match and extract the route params from the template, I would prefer to use existing functionality to do this.

Problem is, I can't find anything that seems like it'll do this for me. The closest appears to be the internal class `System.Web.Mvc.Routing.InlineRouteTemplateParser` but my experiments with it were not particularly fruitful. Is there anything I can or should be using to achieve this, or should I just give in to the dark regex god?

Comment: I don't think you can account/code for developer typos; surely there are tests ran on your check-in's that confirm these kinds of problems. I'm just trying to understand if what you're trying to achieve is even really necessary? I mean if there are any typos in the object's definition then I would have expected the dev to have written a test to check this, assuming a TDD approach to development is in place?

Comment: This seems messy. I cant put my finger on it but something isn't clicking for me. I think its that query strings are strings, not objects. Before editing an T4 template, I'd double check you cant use a Method Name and with specific Route Tables as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 There is another idea I have with a generic ToStringMethod which unfortunately uses reflection & you might force correct Dictionary Name/Value pairs are parsed properly, see this project: https://github.com/chillitom/ToStringBuilder

Comment: @JeremyThompson Not sure why you are talking about query strings here, since those are not part of a route?

Comment: I want to help you, this problem is on my mind and it's 1am here. Is there any extra info?